# How to make cache key if method parameter is Interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, ehcache

I've a method which accept `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable` as parameter.
When user request for **page = 0 and size = 20** and so on then I want to make these passed values as `cache key`.

What I did is

```
@Cacheable(key = "#pageable.number")
public Person getPersons(Pageable pageable)
```

It's giving axception :

> EL1008E: Property or field 'number' cannot be found on object of type
>   'org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest' - maybe not public?

How can I make cache key it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property is called `pageNumber` not `number`

```
@Cacheable(key = "#pageable.pageNumber")
public Person getPersons(Pageable pageable)
```

The general sense of using the cache this way can be questioned though. But that's maybe out of scope for this question.

Comment: This works!!! what is `The general sense of using the cache this way can be questioned though`. Please add this also, would be very helpful.

Comment: first, I hope this is just pseudocode and you're actually returning a `Page` or `Collection` and not a single `Person` object. Then you also have very thorough with cache invalidation otherwise you'd end up with stale data.